# how to apply SWIM protocol on a x86 gpio?

Tags: linux, x86, driver, gpio

It's a weird senario. We use a x86 soc as the host and a stm8s MCU as client. They are connected with 2 wires between the GPIOs(sOC side) and RST and SWIM(MCU side). So in this way we can reflash the MCU firmware by the SWIM protocol.

Here is the problem. After we enter the SWIM mode(enter sequence is easily UP/DOWN by gpio operations on low frequency), we need to send data to MCU. But the protocol need to send data with a high frequency(16M clock). I have try with a simple gpio operation with no delay:

```
for(i=0; i<10; i++) {
    gpio_set_value(SWIM, 0);
    gpio_set_value(SWIM, 1);
}
```

But on the oscilloscope the pulse will delay 2ns for both UP/DOWN. I think it maybe the io speed limit or some other system reason. As the SWIM protocol said, to send data the minimal delay is about 0.25ns.

Are there any ways to speed up the GPIO operations? or do we have some special method to apply this request?

BTW: We are using linux on the soc.

Comment: Depends a lot on what `gpio_set_value()` actually does.

Comment: Thanks J, gpio_set_value do quite a few judge and validate work. But x86 is a complicated thing, I don't think control the GPIO register is a good idea.

Comment: I found some examples for SWIM. But all of them are run on a real time system. They use DMA+TIMER on a STM32. Could we use this method to achieve the high GPIO frequency?